# App that toggles images via web requests

Tags: rest, web-applications

I'm looking to set up a harness such that the application-under-test will scan the images in order to run the tests. Different tests will use different images, so I would need to be a web app that is controlled by the test framework to toggle images through REST or any web request.

The closest one that meets my need is the digital frames but there appears to be no way to programmatically switch the images.

Appreciate people's thoughts if there are any other apps available in the market that closely suits this requirements, otherwise, please post your ideas to build one.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

[WebSocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) and [WebSocketServer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) ! Server socket processes the request and distributes back to the connected clients. By that way, the test will request change of image where the server will respond back with the new image resource to the other client connections that instantly reloads the new image.